# Matlab center a matrix to its mean

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to centre a matrix to its mean,

```
A[i][j] = A[i][j]-mean(A,j)
```

So I subtract from each point the mean of the according column.
I could not find a function to centre my data, and it is not very straightforward to create my own

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
>> A=[1 4 7;2 5 8;3 6 9]

A =

     1     4     7
     2     5     8
     3     6     9

>> A-repmat(mean(A),size(A,1),1)

ans =

    -1    -1    -1
     0     0     0
     1     1     1
```

Comment: I have found this one:Maybe doing the same thing detrend(A,'constant');

Comment: Which of these two should I prefer?

Comment: I guess mine is pretty straightforward, if you later return to your code you can understand what is going on easily. Moreover, `detrend` has some additional options like breakpoints and stuff which you don't care about so probably `repmat` will do faster.

Comment: Ok I have a problem.I created a random script to implement the center:function D=center(A)
f=mean(A);
for i=1:size(A,2),
    D(:,i)=A(:,i)-f(i);
end
end
Why its so slow in comparison to other 2?

Comment: It is faster in matlab to use vectorized code instead of loops.

Comment: the problem is the re allocation of memory in variable D ?

Comment: yeah also you should pre-allocate, if the variable is growing inside the loop , it will make things slower.

Answer (score 7):

```
A = bsxfun(@minus,A,mean(A));
```

for example:

```
A = magic(5);
A = bsxfun(@minus, A, mean(A))
A =

     4    11   -12    -5     2
    10    -8    -6     1     3
    -9    -7     0     7     9
    -3    -1     6     8   -10
    -2     5    12   -11    -4
```